# Javascript sessions on node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

Is it possible to assign sessions to variables on a node.js server. 
I have an application that has some collaboration functionality and for that I need the variables be unique to sessions using javascript.

Is there a way this can be done? Please advice.

Comment: Yes.  Have a look at Express.js, it has full support for sessions if you want it, and a variety of session stores.

Comment: Take a look about ExpressJs sessions: [link](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/)